# ColorEditor missing from System.Drawing.Design?

Tags: c#, colors, xna

I'm trying to use the `ColorEditor` class, according to Microsoft it's located in `System.Drawing.Design`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.coloreditor.aspx,

however despite using that namespace the compiler says

> it can't find `ColorEditor`, I checked myself in `System.Drawing.Design` and found it wasn't there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Kinda creepy when the compiler starts to talk back to you like that.  It normally says "Are you missing an assembly reference?"  You do of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add reference to `System.Drawing.Design` assembly. Note that this assembly is not a part of .NET FW Client Profile.

Comment: There is no System.Drawing.Design in the assembly references, just System.Drawing. I'm trying to compile the Gleed2D project (http://gleed2d.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets), when I load it up it says it needs to be converted for VS2010, which goes without a hitch but in the assembly references it has a yellow exclamation mark next to the System.Drawing.Design assembly reference saying it's unavailable or not yet built.. The System.Drawing.Design assembly is not available either when I try to add it.

Comment: Just to add I manually found the System.Drawing.Design.dll and added it, and it still showed up with the yellow exclamation mark...

Comment: Your project might target .NET FW 3.5 Client Profile or .NET FW 4.0 Client Profile. System.Drawing.Design is not available for client profiles, you must target full framework to use it.

Comment: Check `Application` tab in project properties, `Target framework` option.

Answer (score 2):

Have you added `System.Drawing.Design` to the project reference ?